# TextRenderer.MeasureText() and textbox maximum text length

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, textrenderer

I have a long string (~100k characters). I need to know the length for this string. I call

```
Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(graphics, text, font);
```

But it returns width equals 7. Only if text length <= 43679 it returns correct value!

Also, if I insert the text in the text box, the text is not visible in the text box! I can select text with mouse, copy via "Ctrl+C", but text not visible. **MaxLength** property is more than the text length.

I've looked on msdn, but haven't found any information about maximum text length which is used in MeasureText and TextBox.

Where I can find documentation about this? Is there any way to increase maximum text length? Do these values depend on the operating system and computer performance?

Comment: I've heard of this problem before, it is a Windows bug.  The kind that do exist when you do insane things like this.  The workaround is pretty obvious, if the string contains more than a thousand characters then you just don't care anymore how wide the string might be, it is never going to fit.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709069/the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-textbox-can-display

Comment: Related_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355427/is-43679-a-magic-number

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867395/cant-insert-more-than-43679-character-to-sql-server-single-cell

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for measuring strings, textrenderer isnt accurate

```
protected int _MeasureDisplayStringWidth ( Graphics graphics, string text, Font font )
{
    if ( text == "" )
        return 0;

    StringFormat format = new StringFormat ( StringFormat.GenericDefault );
    RectangleF rect = new RectangleF ( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
    CharacterRange[] ranges = { new CharacterRange ( 0, text.Length ) };
    Region[] regions = new Region[1];

    format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges ( ranges );
    format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

    regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges ( text, font, rect, format );
    rect = regions[0].GetBounds ( graphics );

    return (int)( rect.Right );
}
```

credit to [problem with TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116216/problem-with-textrenderer-measuretext)

Other then that also try using stringbuilder with long strings and then even split the strings into smaller ones and measure those and add it together

Comment: It does not work. graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rect, format) throw "A generic error occurred in GDI+." exception with long text length (ex. 100k characters).

Comment: my tests: the maximum length for MeasureCharacterRanges is only 32 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Similar example was given [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8x6dy3w(v=vs.110).aspx) . Also they addressed the maxLength issue on 
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8x6dy3w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Important : See how the MaxLength is used in the article.

```
private static void DrawALineOfText(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Declare strings to render on the form. 
    string[] stringsToPaint = { "Tail", "Spin", " Toys" };

    // Declare fonts for rendering the strings.
    Font[] fonts = { new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular), 
        new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Italic), 
        new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular) };

    Point startPoint = new Point(10, 10);

    // Set TextFormatFlags to no padding so strings are drawn together.
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

    // Declare a proposed size with dimensions set to the maximum integer value.
    Size proposedSize = new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

    // Measure each string with its font and NoPadding value and  
    // draw it to the form. 
    for (int i = 0; i < stringsToPaint.Length; i++)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.Graphics, stringsToPaint[i], 
            fonts[i], proposedSize, flags);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(startPoint, size);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, stringsToPaint[i], fonts[i],
            startPoint, Color.Black, flags);
        startPoint.X += size.Width;
    }

}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8x6dy3w(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I saw this code. It does not explain why TextRenderer.MeasureText() do not work when the text is long.