# Can't insert more than 43679 character to sql server single cell?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to insert 500 000 characters to sql server single cell. But, I can't insert more than 43679 characters to single cell.

I tried to create table:

```
create table sample1(name nvarchar(max)
create table sample2(address ntext)
```

But I didn't succeed

Comment: How did you verify that only 43679 characters were inserted in a column?

Comment: please also add how you are inserting into the table

Comment: Are you copy/pasting in Grid Mode??? Write a query!

Comment: The following proves that you can -- `CREATE TABLE #T (Col NVARCHAR(MAX)); INSERT #T (Col) VALUES(REPLICATE(CAST('|' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 10000000)); SELECT LEN(Col) FROM #T; DROP TABLE #T;`

Comment: I tried to insert insert into test values('123456...')

Comment: upto 5 lack character

Comment: Please help me to solve this issues. How I can insert more that 3 lack chatacter to the cell

Comment: The very short sample query I posted will create a table, and insert a record with 10,000,000 characters (1,000 lakh), then check the string length to confirm it is still the right length (which it is). Therefore the problem is not with SQL Server's ability to store a character of this length, it is with how you are trying to insert it, but you haven't posted the code you are using to either insert the data, or verify its length, so currently nobody can tell you what you are doing wrong because nobody knows what you are doing at all.

Comment: thanks now woking fine

Comment: please don't use Indian words here

Comment: Is there any limitation in retrial process, how many char can be retrieve in a cell?

Answer (score 8):

The issue does not come from the column type:

- nvarchar(max) can hold 2GB of data (more than 1 billion chars)
- ntext should not be used as it is deprecated and can hold 1GB of data (more than 500 million chars)

The issue seems to be when you get the data. If you are copy/pasting, just paste in a notepad to see if your data is complete.

Note that there is a known issue when you copy/paste in Grid Mode with SSMS 2008+:

- [SSMS - Can not paste more than 43679 characters from a column in Grid Mode](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507222635/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode)

So you could install SSMS 2005 or see if the workarounds listed here could fit your requirements:

- [SSMS - Allow large text to be displayed in as a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507221103/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499618/ssms-allow-large-text-to-be-displayed-in-as-a-link)

Comment: lot of thanks. I tried to use LEN query. Now only i understood the problem. Thanks