# Not able to save more than 43679 char in text datatype column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

I have a column in table with `text` datatype and trying to save some string value to this column from C# code. Issue comes when I use some very large string.

I am not able to save more than 43679 character into text field. I know `text` size can be 2^31.

I also tried saving same value from SSMS and noticed same scenario.

There is nothing special about code, but still SQL query is given below...

```
update TableName
set ColumnName = 'some text more than 43679 char'
where id=<some int id>
```

just to mention... column is declare in table as

```
[columnname] [text] NULL
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong.

Comment: What is the error you got when you run the query?

Comment: Just google for 43679 :)

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for info.... I'll update my column with varchar(max)..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709069/the-maximum-number-of-characters-a-textbox-can-display

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355427/is-43679-a-magic-number

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759721/how-do-i-view-the-full-content-of-a-text-or-varcharmax-column-in-sql-server-20

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867395/cant-insert-more-than-43679-character-to-sql-server-single-cell

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460390/sql-server-ntext-field-limited-to-43-679-characters

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847121/unicode-characters-get-truncated-nvarcharmax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use  `varchar(max)` to store huge amount of data. See [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189087.aspx)

> We recommend that you store large data by using the varchar(max),
>   nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max) data types. To control in-row and
>   out-of-row behavior of these data types, use the large value types out
>   of row option.

You can also check the same issue here: [SSMS - Can not paste more than 43679 characters from a column in Grid Mode](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/499608/ssms-can-not-paste-more-than-43679-characters-from-a-column-in-grid-mode)

Comment: Thanks... This is actually SSMS issue and still open with Microsoft team.

Comment: @Abhash786:- You are welcome. Indeed but the Microsoft team has also asked to used `varchar(max)` now to store huge data and may be `text` will be deprecated soon(*although no official news about it*);)

Comment: @Thanks Rahul... I think varchar(max) can go till 8000 bytes or 2 GB... Right?

Comment: @Abhash786:- Indeed, which is quite a big amount of data to store...right? ;)