# Unicode characters get truncated nvarchar(max)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am storing some Unicode data(text) in sql server in table definition i have `nvarchar(max)` which I guess have capacity to store `2^31` characters.

When I store 696829 Unicode characters it saves only 43 thousands(43679) characters only.

Comment: Can you please post your table schema and a small repro

Comment: please google '43679 characters in sql server'. There are lots of posts around there.

Comment: People seem to have found success by using the MS advised varchar .. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495535/not-able-to-save-more-than-43679-char-in-text-datatype-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: Confirm with SELECT LEN(fieldname) FROM table..., not cut and paste from SSMS.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits) will be useful.

Comment: thank you guys for help :)
i figured it out by seeing this 
https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/02/18/sql-server-management-studio-and-very-large-strings/